# Mesh lines visible in object mode

Tags: interface, object-mode

hey there i was just applying some modifier [ mirror ] , then suddenly the mesh started to look like this somewhat a mix between wireframe and solid mode . how do  stop this from happening coz i feel its irritating ,
[image]
note : draw all edges is off.

and also it happens to only one particular mesh .AND YAH I HAD CLOSED THE SOFTWARE ONCE SO I CANT UNDO IT .

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: looks a bit like z-fighting....is it possible that your object is doubled?